# Why does Try/catch in ActionBlock not catch this error sometimes?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using an ActionBlock in a web crawler I'm writing.

Sometimes when I call

```
actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

I get the following error

> One or more errors occurred.

With the inner exception being

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

This is the full code block below.

```
actionBlock = new ActionBlock<URLsToCheckObject>(URLToCheck =>
{
    try
    {
        // get more urls etc here and post below

        actionBlock.Post(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = CleanURL, Host = host });
        if (actionBlock.InputCount == 0) actionBlock.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 3 catch...", WebsiteToCrawl);
        }
        catch { }
    }

}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token });

actionBlock.Post(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = WebsiteToCrawl.website, Host = host });

try
{
    Logger.AddToDebugLog("Waiting on action block..", WebsiteToCrawl);
    actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch..." + ex.Message, WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch..." + ex.InnerException, WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch...", WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Why would the try/catch that wraps the entire contents of the `ActionBlock` not catch this exception?

Comment: You are manipulating the [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) inside its own delegate. I don't think that this class is designed to be used like this. If you want to create a loop where the end of the pipeline is adding more elements to the pipeline, you should probably use a linked [`BufferBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) before the `ActionBlock`, and have the `ActionBlock` post to the `BufferBlock`.

Comment: @jamie that's *not* how Dataflow blocks are supposed to work. This code is essentially an infinite loop that treats the ActionBlock as if it were just a queue. You don't tell the block to complete from *inside* it, it completes automatically when upstream blocks complete. If you want to generate more URLs, you do so in a previous step. The code doesn't have to be so complicated at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception comes normally from:

```cs
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

since you did not uses the `CancellationToken` inside your lambda, but it is used as a parameter for:

```cs
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token }
```

the `TaskCanceledException` does not come from your lambda (but probably from inside of `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` or `ActionBlock`) so it is outside the scope of your try/catch inside the lambda, and so it does not catch.

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionBlock<>` is there to schedule the processing of all the items you `Post` it to. So there is more code to execute than what you implemented in your lambda. (Just like `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task.Run()` have more to execute than the code you pass).

The `ActionBlock<>` has to wait for incoming elements and thereby also to check if it should be cancelled. Even if there are incoming items, it checks if cancellation has been requested **before** calling your code, hence *outside* your `try` block.

So if cancellation is requested while the block is only waiting for items, but not currently processing an item in your lambda, you can't catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As you start the action before entering the try, is it possible that the exception occurs too soon?

Move `actionBlock.Post(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = WebsiteToCrawl.website, Host = host });` inside the `try catch`